# how to select all item in consecutive divs with same name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm having a slight problem: I want to select all items consecutively like.

```
<div class="exp1">
    <div class="inn">
        // some code is here
    </div>
    <div class="inn">
        // some code
    </div> 
    //similar divs
</div>//end of exp1


<div class="exp1">
    <div class="inn">
        // some code is here
    </div>
    <div class="inn">
        // some code
    </div> 
    //similar divs
</div>//end of exp1
```

There is no typing mistake. So I want to select all the "inn" divs and make some css change like height and width according to their corresponding "exp1" div, but when I am using jQuery it only selects the first one. The jQuery I'm using is:

```
$('div.exp1 div.inn').each(
                        $(this).css({
            width:$('div.exp1').width()-1,
            height:$('div.exp1').height()-1
            }););
```

Comment: `class+"inn"` and there's no typing mistake?

Comment: `class+"inn"` is that a new syntax u r following if it is case then its hard to help

Comment: _when i am using jquery it only selects the first one_ Could you please post that code!

Comment: Where is your selector? Can you show us what you've tried? The gerenal way to select elements based on their class would be `.inn` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.exp1 div.inn').each(function() {
                    $(this).css({
        width:$(this).parent().width()-1,
        height:$(this).parent().height()-1
        }});
```

Comment: you could improve the code by assigning `$(this)` to a variable instead of calling the `$()` function 3 times

Answer (score 1):

Assign the "inn" class to all divs you want to select like this `<div class="inn"></div>`

Then what you to do is

```
$('.inn').each(function() {
  $(this).css('width', '30px');
});
```

Comment: you don't need the `.each()` since `.css()` will take care of that internally (as will most of the jQuery functions)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed he needs a more general answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your jQuery, but based on your markup (and that you've fixed the typo that you insisted didn't exist), the following will select all elements with the class name `inn` applied:

```
var elements = $(".inn");
```

Comment: please see the question now

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('.inn').each(function(){
   var current_inndiv=$(this);
    current_inndiv.css('width', '30px');

})
```

Comment: you don't need the .each() since .css() will take care of that internally (as will most of the jQuery functions)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){
 $('div.inn').css('width','30px');
});`

I think it will fix your problem